# Slow addSnapshotListener responses + High CPU Usage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In a standard chat app, my client first seeks its subscribed chat rooms,

then listens to all chat room data. In pseudo:

```
db.collection('chatrooms').where('members.\(mySelf)',1)
.addSnapshotListner(chatRooms) {

   chatRooms.forEach { room in 

       room.collection('messages').addSnapshotListener() { ... }

   }

}
```

This causes a 100% CPU peak for about 10 seconds with about ~10 chat rooms. I have verified that even when executing no code at all within the internal snapshot listener callback this still happens - i.e. the subscription itself is resource-heavy.

**It's important to say that when I turn offline persistence off, the addSnapshotListener behaves normally and doesn't use a lot of CPU resources.**

I'm not sure whether I've architected this in a wrong way or is this maybe a bug?

I'm trying to reach a behavior where the user can just open up the app, enter one of the first chat rooms and see messages as quickly as possible.

The other method I've tried is listening to each chat room whenever the user clicks, but even though the initial data snapshot comes from local cache, it still takes about 0.5-1.0s to load all data (messages subcollection + members subcollection) before the user can see any data.

I'm using the 0.9.2 Swift SDK.

**Update: This happens only in iOS 10, in iOS 11 it works fine**

Comment: did you find the solution as i am facing same issue

Comment: @PatelJigar it seems the problem went away after upgrading the SDK to version 4.13.0

Answer (score 0):

I see a typo in your snippet

```
db.collection('chatrooms').where('members.\(mySelf)',1)
.addSnapshotListner(chatRooms) {

   chatRooms.forEach { room in 

       room.collection('messages').addSnapshotListener() { ... }

   }

}
```

It's written Listner instead of Listener(second line)